# No funciona ejecutar los test de Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, test, testing

estoy intentado ejecutar el archivo tests.py de Django pero no he podido hacerlo, cada vez me dice que no encuentra el modulo pasado.

La estructura es así:

```
proyecto/
    |---apps/
       |---productos/
           |--- __init__.py
           |--- admin.py
           |--- ...
           |--- tests.py
           |--- ...
```

Dentro de la carpeta test tengo:

```
class productListViewTest(TestCase):
   
    def stock_product_gt_zero(self):
        maker = Maker.objects.create(manufacturer_name="Lácteos Montenuevo")
        category = Category.objects.create(product_category="Lácteos")
        product = Product.objects.create(
            name_product = 'Crema de leche',
            price = 15.00,
            Manufacturer = maker,
            product_type = category,
            due_date = "21/07/2021"
        )

        url = reverse("product:detail_product", args=(product.id,))
        response = self.client.get(url) 
        self.assertContains(response, product.name_product)
```

Ejecuto desde la terminal (a la altura del manage.py) **>>> python manage.py test**, y este es el resultado:

```
Found 0 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

**>>> python manage.py test apps/productos**, da el mismo resultado

Ejecuto **>>> python manage.py test apps/productos.tests**, el resultado es este:

```
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: apps/productos (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: apps/productos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps/productos'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Dice que no encuentra el modulo: apps/productos (es lo que al final entiendo)

He intentado también con: **>>> python manage.py test productos.tests.productListViewTest.stock_product_gt_zero**, este es el resultado:

```
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: productos (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: productos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'productos'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Ciertamente he intentado de varias formas y el problema es que no encuentra el modulo productos, busque información y no di con la solución, deje todo eso para mostrar lo que he intentado, ello entre otro par de formas (a la hora de ejecutar el python manage.py test) como:

- python manage.py test apps (no encuentra ningún test)
- python manage.py test productos (encuentra test, pero da error que no
  encuentra el modulo productos)
- python manage.py test productos.test (lo mismo que el anterior)

Gracias por leer esto

Answer (score 0):

Como estaba algo novato en los **test** pase algo desapercibido, la manera en como deben de ser construidas las funciones, un ejemplo es este:
(Tomado de la documentación)

```
def test_animals_can_speak(self):
    """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
    ...
```

Allí nos muestra que las funciones deben iniciar con la frase `test`, algo que yo estaba obviando en las funciones que creé, ejem:

```
def animals_can_speak(self):
    """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
    ...
```

Entonces al organizar el nombre de la función, al hacer la ejecución `python manage.py test` ya encuentra todo correctamente.